# What is the correct snowspeeder to pair with the AT-AT?

Tags: star-wars, compatibility

Wanting to replicate the scene from [Empire Strikes Back](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3acC49W3yQk) where Luke is flying a snowspeeder on Hoth and harpoons an AT-AT. I have already purchased and built the AT-AT model number [75288](https://brickset.com/sets/75288) but I'm having trouble figuring out what is right for this scene? Is it the discontinued model [75259](https://brickset.com/sets/75259) or [75268](https://brickset.com/sets/75268)?

**Edit:**

I'm looking to replicate the scene with the current AT-AT I have but I'm unsure which Snowspeeder should be used that will pair well in size with the AT-AT. The Snowspeeders I've researched are different sizes and I'm unsure if [75259](https://brickset.com/sets/75259) is an oversized representation to be used as a model only or if [75268](https://brickset.com/sets/75268) is the correct size representation for the scene. From my research doesn't appear they'll come out with any other variations to a Snowspeeder.

Comment: What do you mean by "right" or "correct"? (1) Which is the most accurate to the models used in the movie? (2) Which has the closest scale? (3) Which offers the most pleasing aesthetic combination? (4) Which has functions allowing to recreate the scenes of the movie? Please update your question with the criterion you are looking for, to make it objectively answerable.

Answer (score 11):

**Taking the most probable and most objectively answerable interpretation ("Which has the closest scale?") the answer can be clearly decided:**

According to the [Star Wars Wiki](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Armored_Transport/Legends) the AT-AT is 22,5 meters high and 20 meters long. The [75288](https://brickset.com/sets/75288) set you purchased is 34 cm high and 38 cm long, this gives a 1:66,17 or 1:52,63 scale, depending on whether you take the height or the length. *(On a side note, here we can see that the LEGO model itself is already not to scale with the movie model.)*

Using these scales the [5,3 meter length](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Snowspeeder) of the Snowspeeder would be the best depicted by a model 10,07 or 8,00 cm long. Of your alternatives the [75268](https://brickset.com/sets/75268) is a bit closer to it at 11 cm, while the [75259](https://brickset.com/sets/75259) is about twice as large (18 cm).

Comment: Huh, I wonder where the discrepancy comes from?  According to your source, the movie version is higher than it is long while the LEGO model is reversed - is it possible they're not counting the head in its length for the movie version?  Or is the LEGO version really that far off in its proportions?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman checking the page zovits has linked I can see there is no exact data on dimensions of the models seen in movies. Based on details found on SW Wiki height could be 15.5-18.5-22.5 meters, or somewhere in the middle. So LEGO model could actually be within the correct proportions.

Comment: @Alex Does anyone have an officially licensed, *non-LEGO* model of an AT-AT they can measure?  Those are likely to be more accurate since they're not constrained the way that LEGO models can be just based on pieces available/structural stability, etc.  Could even use a CG model out of a video game if someone has the wherewithal to extract it.  I'm just curious whose numbers are closer...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman LEGO is not in the business of making movie accurate models, but toys that resemble those, while being assembled from mostly generic bricks, in a way that is statically and structurally sound so that it can be played with and in the correct price range. Achieving all of that necessitates various compromises, in this case the height / length ratio was sacrificed. The question about the non-LEGO model is not on topic here, so you'd have better chances on sites dedicated to the topic.

Comment: Normally, I'd agree that other models are off-topic, but given that this question is specifically about getting as close to movie-accurate proportions as possible, if the best easily-accessible source for movie-accurate proportions is by measuring a non-LEGO model, I do think it's at least somewhat relevant to ask that.

Comment: Another thing to point out about most toys of the AT-AT (I've got an original LEGO one and a Mirco Machines version, and my brother had the old Kenner toy as well) is that they are never correctly scaled to the figures that go with them - in the films the command section clearly has two seated pilots and then a standing gunner, most toys hold two seated figures in there. Even the old Kenner was longer than it was tall - most of the playability is in the head/body rather than having really tall legs...

Comment: Where as the snowspeeders are designed to carry 2 people, and so the scale of those is usually more correctly proportioned to the figures within them.