# What is the correct Snowspeeder to pair with the UCS AT-AT?

Tags: star-wars, scale

What is the correct sized Snowspeeder to pair with the [UCS AT-AT (75313)](https://brickset.com/sets/75313-1/AT-AT)?

Comment: Related https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/16383/what-is-the-correct-snowspeeder-to-pair-with-the-at-at

Answer (score 12):

From [Brickset](https://brickset.com/article/65511/review-75313-at-at#:%7E:text=The%20vehicle%20measures%2062cm%20in%20height%20and%2069cm%20long): "The vehicle measures 62cm in height and 69cm long".

The same measurements of a [real AT-AT](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Armored_Transport/Legends#:%7E:text=Length,22.5%20meters) would be 22.5 meters and 20 meters.

Therefore the 75313 is scaled between 1:36 and 1:29, depending on whether the height or the length is more important.

A model of the 5.3 meters long [Snowspeeder](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Snowspeeder#:%7E:text=Length,5.3%20meters) at these scales would be anywhere between 14.7 and 18.2 cm long, so the [75259: Snowspeeder – 20th Anniversary Edition](https://brickset.com/sets/75259) at 18 cm would definitely be in the correct scale range, and it has a passing level of details as well.

[image: Maybe replace the stud shooter if you strive for display accuracy though...]